# how to remove all lines containg less than n number of items

Tags: vim, sed, awk, vi

I want to remove all lines containing less than **n** number of items, space separated.

Say I want to remove lines containing less than 3 items. So the file below:

```
sdf sdfsdf sdfgsdf sdfsdfsd
sdf sdfsdf 
sdf sdfsdf sdfgsdf 
sdf sdfsdf sdfgsdf  ertert
```

Should result in:

```
sdf sdfsdf sdfgsdf sdfsdfsd
sdf sdfsdf sdfgsdf 
sdf sdfsdf sdfgsdf  ertert
```

**Actually both `awk` and `sed` solutions are acceptable.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
awk 'NF >= 3' filename
```

Comment: If you have the number as a shell value: `awk -v n=$num 'NF>=n' file`

Comment: I thought about adding that, but I figured simpler was better. Thanks though, for making my answer more complete.

Answer (score 4):

In vim:

```
:v/\(\S\+\s\+\)\{3,}/d
```

Another option is

```
:g/./exec len(split(getline('.'))) < 3 ? 'd' : ''
```

You could also do something interesting like

```
:py vim.current.buffer[:] = [l for l in vim.current.buffer if len(l.split()) >= 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a vi solution, but this is so dead simple in perl:

```
ethan@rover:~$ perl -ne 'print if split > 3' foo
```

where "foo" is your file.

Comment: Good on MJB.  awk is more appropriate than Perl in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a vim tag:

```
:v/\(\S\+\s\)\{2,}\S/d
```

Replace 2 with n-1.

Answer (score 1):

NF is the number of fields in the record. Replace 2 with number you want

```
awk '{if (NF > 2) print $0}' inputFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
~$ cat test.txt | awk '{if(length($3) > 0) print $0;}'
```

Hope this helps